# SQL Query: User/Group/Role and UserGroup/GroupRole Connecting User to Role

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good evening,

I have been struggling with what I think should be a fairly basic SQL query, but I can't seem to figure it out. Particularly because it seems as if there are multiple approaches (joins/ sub-queries).

I have three primary tables, and two tables connecting them.

```
USER
uID - PK
name, email, ...

GROUP
gID - PK
name

ROLE
rID - PK
permission

USERGROUP
uID - FK
gID - FK

GROUPROLE
gID - FK
rID - FK
```

These are many to many relationships, such that a user can be in multiple groups, and a group can have multiple roles.

I would like to have a query that ultimately gives me all of the roles that are connected to a given user through the groups that he belongs. Thus the uID is known, but nothing else. The output could have as few as one column with the rID, as that is all I really need for the program logic.

Is it possible to perform a query on the result of a previous query? I can easily find all the groups a user is in, and given each group, I can easily find the roles associated, but I get tripped up by the fact that there are many groups associated with a user, not just a single one which would be easier.

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just `join`s and aggregation:

```
select array_agg(distinct r.permission) as permissions
from usergroups ug join
     grouproles gr
     on ug.gid = gr.gid join
     roles r
     on gr.rid = r.id
where ug.uid = ?;
```

If you want the permissions in separate rows, then:

```
select distinct r.permission
from usergroups ug join
     grouproles gr
     on ug.gid = gr.gid join
     roles r
     on gr.rid = r.id
where ug.uid = ?;
```

I am leaving the `distinct` because different groups could share the same permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting the information that I need now, but I have one follow up question:

The result when I run it is a single cell with all of the permissions associated with the user. What if I wanted each permission to be in a row all to itself?

When I use sample data, for example, I get the following:

PERMISSIONS
{read, write}

And if I wanted:

PERMISSIONS
read
write

Pardon the formatting, although I think my question is clear.

Comment: I answered that myself. Simply removing the array_agg did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sad-EyedLadyoftheLowlands: If this is the answer you were looking for, you should accept it by clicking the check/tick next to it.